# Why hasn't Tom Selleck done more big screen work?

Tags: tom-selleck

Tom Selleck is a highly recognizable name and face in Hollywood and is well known for his roles in television and the big screen. In looking over his list of roles on IMDb I realized he is still quite active however has not had many big screen roles, especially in the past 20 years or so. Most of his leading big screen roles were in the 80s or early 90s. Out of 83 titles, only 24 of them are big screen movies while many of the others are TV movies.

So does he just prefer television roles? Does he purposely avoid the big screen or does he have a crappy agent or is he hard to work with...? Just seems like he has a big enough presence and reputation that he could be a big screen star still so I wonder why he doesn't do them.

Clarification: I am looking for any concrete quotes or interviews where Tom Selleck or someone who has worked with him has mentioned anything regarding the fact that he hasn't done more big screen work. I'm not asking for user's opinions or theories.

Comment: @Paulie_D that's exactly what I'm looking or is an answer on whether there's any explanation out there through interviews or otherwise. Not looking for an opinion.

Comment: I think any answer is going to have to be opinion-based because the "answer" involves a set of intangibles.  Still a valid question, imo, having moved in industry circles.

Comment: @Paulie_D You don't actually need him to come here for answering, though. A majority of the answering work we do here is compiling sources from all across the media and the press.

Comment: Thanks all...the question has been clarified and bonus, I actually found a Selleck quote on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He's married and he works hard at it...

Source: [**People Magazine**](http://www.people.com/people/archive/article/0,,20595693,00.html)

> Once focused mainly on his career-as the star of the '80s smash hit Magnum, P.I., "I worked 90 hours a week and did a movie every break"-Selleck, 67, took a big step back from the spotlight in 1988 when his wife, actress Jillie Mack, 54, gave birth to daughter Hannah. **"I quit Magnum to have a family," he says. "It took a long time to get off the train, but I try very hard to have balance, and this ranch has helped me do that."**

and

> As part of that balance, he works only every other week taping Blue Bloods in New York City and shoots his popular annual Jesse Stone TV films... in less than a month on location in Halifax, N.S. **“My first priority,” Selleck says, “is time with my family.”**
>
> “It’s important to nurture your marriage,” he says. “I think wanting time away from work has been good for that.” Selleck and Mack also attribute Hannah’s maturity to their country lifestyle. “We both thought,” says Jillie, “it was the best environment for her to grow up.”

Answer (score 2):

He tried to make the transition back in the 80's, but it never really took.

It's a weird thing. Many actors can "carry" a TV show, but it's a much smaller number that can "carry" a feature film. *[Tom Hanks and Jennifer Aniston are examples of actors who started out in TV, but were able to make the transition to movies. This tends to be fairly rare, although you do see it more often with comedians, such as SNL former cast members.]*

Regarding Selleck, it's probably also financial. I'm sure he could get plenty of supporting work in film, but being the lead on a TV show likely pays better.

Comment: Aniston...not so much though...:)

Comment: Aniston seems to have completely transitioned to film.  (Nothing like Hanks though. That guy became a box office monster, and he started out on TV, wearing a dress;)

Comment: Transitioned maybe but she's not on the radar much AFAIK.

Comment: Not these days, it's true. But she does have a lot of leading film roles in her past, and hasn't moved back to TV like Courtney Cox.

Comment: I think that you're forgetting the cinematic gem that is _Three Men and a Baby_ ;)

Comment: Good reference @steelerfan!  However, this falls into "back in the 80's" and it was an ensemble cast.  (**Quigley Down Under** and **Lassiter** should also be mentioned ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know.  I just can't pass up the opportunity to throw out a _Three Men and a Baby_ reference ;)

Comment: very good point!